# Nested schema for $jsonSchema property 'description' must be an object", 'code': 14, 'codeName': 'TypeMismatch'

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

So I am trzing to create MongoDB validator in python using `pymongo`.

This is how my schema looks:

```
user_validator = {
        "$jsonSchema":{
            "bsonType": "object",
            "required": ["user_email", "user_name", "rules"],
            "properties":{
                "user_email": {
                    "bsonType": "string",
                    "description": "must be string and is required"
                },
                "user_name":{
                    "bsonType": "string",
                    "description": "must be a string and is required"
                },
                "rules": {
                        "bsonType": "array",
                        "items":{
                            "bsonType": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "name":{
                                    "bsonType": "string",
                                    "description": "must be string"
                                },
                                "commit_hashes":{
                                    "bsonType": "array",
                                    "items":{
                                        "bsonType": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "hash": {
                                                "bsonType": "string",
                                                "description": "must be string"
                                            },
                                            "date": {
                                                "bsonType": "string",
                                                "description": "must be string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "description": "must be object"
                                    },
                                    "description": "must be array"
                                }
                            },
                            "description": "must be Object"
                        }
                        },
                        "description": "must be array of objects and is required" 
                    }
                },
                "description": "must be array of objects and is required"
            }
```

After running the code I get this error: `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Parsing of collection validator failed :: caused by :: Nested schema for $jsonSchema property 'description' must be an object, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "Parsing of collection validator failed :: caused by :: Nested schema for $jsonSchema property 'description' must be an object", 'code': 14, 'codeName': 'TypeMismatch'}`

And I am not really sure why this is happening. Can someone tell me what is going on here?

Comment: when collapsed it looks like `{"$jsonSchema": {...},"description": "must be array of objects and is required" }` is this correct. or should the description go inside the jsonSchema